# WPF Ribbon - Can we hide AuxiliaryPane of Ribbon ApplicationMenu?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I am using MS Ribbon in my application. 
I want to hide the `AuxiliaryPane` of its `RibbonApplicationMenu` ? I want to show only normal menu items.

I read that it Pane violates the Microsoft Office UI License of Ribbon Control.
But in Microsoft CRM, `AuxillaryPane` is not present.

So is there an option to hide this ?

Regards
GP

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me in Ribbonbar's loaded event

```
private void ribbonBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var grid = (ribbonApplicationMenu.Template.FindName("MainPaneBorder",ribbonApplicationMenu) as Border).Parent as Grid;
         grid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(0);
    }
```